# Adding a custom field of code to a squeeze page

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add a custom field to a squeeze page side bar. I have added a widget containing code for default pages so that a certain form appears on those pages in the side bar. I've been trying to add a custom field to a squeeze page in Wordpress so that I can use a different form (snippet of code) for the squeeze page (which doesn't show widgets from default pages) but the custom field is not appearing.

I know it works as it had done previously. But I don't know what I've done to correct it.

Can anyone on here assist?

Ivor